# Overload equality operator ("=") on Vector2 in F# - different vectors are reported equal

Tags: .net, f#, xna, operator-overloading

Using the math operators works on XNA Vector2s, [thanks to the overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199663.aspx), for example:

```
new Vector2(1.0f, 2.0f) + new Vector2(2.0f, 3.0f) // {X:3 Y:5}
```

(very handy)

But have look at this:

```
// Okay, this works fine.
new Vector2(1.0f, 2.0f) = new Vector2(1.0f, 2.0f) // true
// Is it checking for type equality?
new Vector2(1.0f, 2.0f) = new Vector2(6.0f, 5.0f) // true
```

So why doesn't it call the overloads on Vector2 for `op_Equality` (same deal for `op_Inequality`)? They do work as expected if called directly.

PS: If it matters, which I assume it doesn't, I'm running this under Mono and Monogame.

PPS: This is mainly just annoying that I can't use `=`, but I *can* just use Vector2.Equals if I really need to.

Comment: Have you redefined `(=)` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Not at all, but I thought about doing that to fix this ironically

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there must be some difference between different versions of the MonoGame assemblies, because when I run the code on Windows (using `WindowsGL` version) in F# Interactive, I get the expected result:

```
> #r @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\WindowsGL\MonoGame.Framework.dll" 
  open Microsoft.Xna.Framework;;

> new Vector2(1.0f, 2.0f) = new Vector2(1.0f, 2.0f);;
val it : bool = true
> new Vector2(1.0f, 2.0f) = new Vector2(6.0f, 5.0f);;
val it : bool = false
```

I also tried referencing the assemblies in `Linux` directory (although I did that on Windows) and it works too, so there is something odd going on. Which platform are you using? Can you try running just the above script in F# interactive to test if it works outside of your application?

Comment: Tried that (but of course adapted the path to the correct one on my machine), and it returned true for both comparisons. I'm running F# 3.0 on Mono 2.10.9 under Mac 10.8.2

Answer (score 1):

The F# equality operator can't be overridden, but for non-F# types it should be equivalent to using the non-static `Equals` method (as described by [pseudocode in the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818970)).  Perhaps there's something else going on in your example?

Comment: Hmm, no... I've tested my samples exactly in FSI and it yields the same results... :/

Comment: But yeah, that's what I though it was supposed to do.